# How to solve upgrading Magento 2.1.1 to Magento 2.1.17?

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, composer, magento-2.1.1

I am faced issue when I upgrade Magento 2.1.1 to Magento 2.1.17

I changed some values in composer.json

"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.1",  =>"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.17",

"version": "2.1.1", => "version": "2.1.17",

I keep getting this error message

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an install able set of packages.



Problem 1
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.17, 100.1.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.17, 100.1.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.1.17].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.1.17 requires magento/framework 100.1.17 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.17].
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.17 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.17].
- Installation request for magento/framework == 100.1.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.1].
```

I tried to fix this problem by adding this line

"magento/framework": "100.1.17|100.1.1.*", in "require"

but no luck

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: If answer helpful please accept and upvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make any change in `composer.json` Leave it as it is

Run below code from your `project root`

```
1) composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.17 --no-update
2) composer update
```

Now run below command

```
1) php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
3) php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4) php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now login back to your admin and check your Magento version.

Comment: You're welcome, Help each other..! Happy coding..!